Is .NET MAUI compiling application into Java? Any ideas to speed up the building process?
When i builded my own MAUI app i noticed that building takes a lot of time.
I changed log level of the build to detailed, and the building process hangs like 50 seconds on that command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\openjdk\jdk-17.0.8.101-hotspot\bin\java.exe -Xmx1G -classpath "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.95\tools\r8.jar" com.android.tools.r8.D8 --debug --min-api 21 --output obj\Debug\net8.0-android\android\bin\ --lib "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-34\android.jar" obj\Debug\net8.0-android\android\bin\classes.zip "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Ref.34\34.0.95\ref\net8.0\mono.android.jar" "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\34.0.95\tools\java_runtime_fastdev_net6.jar" C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.jetbrains.annotations\24.0.1.3\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.annotations-24.0.1.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib\1.9.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-1.9.0.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib.jdk7\1.9.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.9.0.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlin.stdlib.jdk8\1.9.0.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlin.kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.9.0.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlinx.coroutines.core.jvm\1.7.2.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-core-jvm-1.7.2.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.kotlinx.coroutines.android\1.7.2.1\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\org.jetbrains.kotlinx.kotlinx-coroutines-android-1.7.2.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.google.guava.listenablefuture\1.0.0.14\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\guava-listenablefuture.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.annotation.jvm\1.6.0.2\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.annotation.annotation-jvm.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.concurrent.futures\1.1.0.14\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.concurrent.concurrent-futures.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.lifecycle.common\2.6.1.3\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.lifecycle.lifecycle-common.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.arch.core.common\2.2.0.3\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.arch.core.core-common.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.resourceinspection.annotation\1.0.1.7\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.resourceinspection.resourceinspection-annotation.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.constraintlayout.core\1.0.4.6\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.constraintlayout.constraintlayout-core.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.androidx.collection.ktx\1.2.0.9\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\androidx.collection.collection-ktx.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.disklrucache\4.15.1.2\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\disklrucache.jar C:\Users\usercatalog\.nuget\packages\xamarin.android.glide.annotations\4.15.1.2\buildTransitive\net6.0-android31.0\..\..\jar\annotations.jar "C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.Mono.android-x64\8.0.7\runtimes\android-x64\native\libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.Android.jar" obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\104\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\105\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\106\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\107\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\108\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\109\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\110\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\111\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\112\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\113\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\114\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\115\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\116\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\117\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\118\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\119\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\120\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\121\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\122\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\123\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\124\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\125\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\126\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\127\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\128\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\129\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\130\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\131\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\132\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\133\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\134\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\134\jl\libs\repackaged.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\135\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\136\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\137\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\138\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\139\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\140\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\141\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\142\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\143\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\144\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\145\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\146\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\147\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\148\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\149\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\150\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\151\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\152\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\153\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\154\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\155\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\156\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\157\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\158\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\159\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\160\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\161\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\162\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\163\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\164\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\165\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\166\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\167\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\168\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\169\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\170\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\172\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\173\jl\libs\ED64959F88B22E6D.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\174\jl\libs\2E7FD15AFA9B216B.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\177\jl\classes.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\180\jl\libs\F975D0960055A5E3.jar obj\Debug\net8.0-android\lp\181\jl\libs\B71CFF5D5A0B3AEB.jar --map-diagnostics warning info

In my opinion it looks like it is compiling a project into a single classfile, and he is doing it only on 1 core. Anyone can confirm if its true?
Any ideas to speed up a building process?

Its not, its just using the JAVA JDK

@FreakyAli if it uses JDK that is translated into Java Development Kit, so it is used to compile java, isnt that ?

It uses JDK to communicate with the native APIs it does not convert code to Java anywhere

I wish Microsoft was as smart as you and realised that they use Java in the background https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/get-started/what-is-xamarin#xamarinandroid https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/xamarin/android/internals/architecture

@FreakyAli thank you for the links, it proves my point. Somehow, i couldn't find them.

I am literally speechless it says exactly the opposite of what you are saying how does it prove your point

Xamarin.Android applications compile from C# into Intermediate Language (IL) which is then Just-in-Time (JIT) compiled to a native assembly when the application launches So it is compiled to IL, and then to native assembly which is Java. I tried to connect to REST API and got exceptions from Java class, not a single line of stack was pointing to my C# code.

Yes the native interface is written in Java by the Android team but your code is never converted to Java though that was my point from the start
